# SpriteKit Game Stages

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm looking to create a sprite kit game with stages like stage 1 , stage 2 ,stage 3,etc .

and i want to create a condition  that if not finish the first stage you can't reach the 2nd one.

what I'm asking for is can you tell me how to create these stages , or lead me to some tutorial to do that.

Comment: This is a very broad question, you could be more specific. Asking for tutorials is not very fruitful.

Comment: sorry for that buddy but i have been so tired of trying :((

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/ has tutorials, they are certainly useful if you want to learn sprite-kit basics, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Easiet would be to store a dictionary of {String: Bool} to hold {stageIndex: isLocked}

You serialize and deserialize this dictionary in NSUserDefaults as needed.

This dictionary is then used to display the locked state on UI elements etc. If locked and the button pressed, run some animation to show that it cant be opened, e.g. blink the button. (assuming the button shows the stage is locked)

When a player passes a stage, unlock the next one and update the dictionary. When you return the the game menu, reload the UI elements using the dictionary so the updated stage states are shown.

```
if isLocked == false
{
    // init the stage and present its scene
}
```

Comment: Seriously? The OP has no idea on how to do levels and you're answering him with dictionary, locked states and NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Well, I would suggest anyone first learn how to setup a dictionary with booleans before writing a multi level spritekit game.

Comment: I certainly do not disagree with you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really too broad to provide a good answer but seeing that you are just starting out, I suggest you create a main menu scene and a separate scene for every level you need. You can then transition back and forth between your main menu and levels scenes.